# String to Double Conversion

Tags: java, string, double

I am getting a decimal value in String format from another system

```
String value = "33.123456".
```

How can i convert it into the 33123456 , without doing String Split for "[.]" and join it again ?

Answer (score 3):

by replacing `.` to *empty* `String` and parsing it to `long`

```
Long.parseLong(value.replace(".", ""));
```

also handle `NumberFormatException`

if you want to handle

```
123.00
```

to make it like

```
123
```

then multiply it with power of 10 as shown below,

```
String str = "123.0";
int numberOfDigitAfterDecimalPoint = str.length() - str.indexOf(".") - 1;
System.out.println(numberOfDigitAfterDecimalPoint);
System.out.println((long)(Double.parseDouble(str) * Math.pow(10.0, numberOfDigitAfterDecimalPoint - 1)));
```

or do string operation to check if all the digits are `0` after `.` then do `substring()` and `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: what if my input is "33123456.00" or "33123456.0023" or "0.33123456"

Comment: let OP specify if he wants to handle it with this scenario in mind @Mahiz

Comment: @ankur good point though, updated answer to handle this scenario as well

Answer (score 0):

```
double value_double = Double.parseDouble(value.replace('.', ''));
```

Refer to the Documentation below:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html